# Eclipse: Cannot install Kotlin plugin

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, plugins

I'm using Eclipse DSL Tools, version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)

When I try to install Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.22, it gives the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Kotlin 1.5.31.v20211018-0606 (org.jetbrains.kotlin.feature.feature.group 1.5.31.v20211018-0606)
  Missing requirement: kotlin-eclipse-ui 1.5.31.v20211018-0606 (org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui 1.5.31.v20211018-0606) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Kotlin 1.5.31.v20211018-0606 (org.jetbrains.kotlin.feature.feature.group 1.5.31.v20211018-0606)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui [1.5.31.v20211018-0606,1.5.31.v20211018-0606]
```

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image: Kotlin Plugin error]

Is there a way to solve this error, a workaround, or someone who could explain me why this happens?

Comment: It wants a Mylyn component but these are no longer included with Eclipse.